# Effects of external bootstrap library not applied on the JS generated html

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a table which is being generated on the webpage after we click he button proceed `<button class="btn btn-default" id="proceed">Proceed</button>` the external library that i have included in order to make multi select boxes is [bootstrap-select](https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/examples/). The problem is that while the library is working normally when i include it in my webpage as :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url();?>/css/bootstrap-select.min.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url();?>/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
```

(using codeignitor as a framework) but it doesn't work on the mutiselets i have in my table which are being generated using Jquery as :

```
$('#proceed').click(function(){
  makeTable();
});
```

and excerpt from the `makeTable` function (which is were the problem lies) is :

```
tbody = '<td><select id="fromstation" name="ratelist_party_base" class="selectpicker"  multiple><option value="example">example</option></select></td>';$("#tab_logic").append(tbody);
```

tab_logic being the id of the desired place to append , while ill like to make a few things clear is the the code is working fine and the table is being generated, the only problem is that the mutiselect boxes in my code are not getting the library applied on them , and yes while i know there are better ways of rendering the table (like bootstrap modal) for example , but due to some development reasons that is not a viable option. so someone shed some wisdom . much appreciated

Comment: I had a similar issue a while back I think its because your inserting after the page loads so nothing gets applied because its after.  Try `$(document.body).on('click', '#proceed', function() {makeTable();
});`

Comment: I tried and the problem still persists , the multi select box doesn't get displayed when i hard code the class name i the tbody variable whatever i do , and iff i use the jquery `addClass()` method it gets displayed but without any effects  -edit- : although i think your assumption is correct that its a page load issue

Answer (score 0):

After appending your html you need to call the **selectpicker()** again. I hope it helps.

```
tbody = '<td><select id="fromstation" name="ratelist_party_base" class="selectpicker"  multiple>'<option value="example">example</option></select></td>';
$("#tab_logic").append(tbody);
$("#fromstation").selectpicker();
```

Comment: not working , tried it , more about it on my comment above